# Is it possible to return a form element AND an ajax response from the same ajax callback function?

Tags: forms, ajax

I have an ajax callback function that needs to return a form element and also an ajax response. Is it possible to do both?

In my callback I need to set and return something like:

```
$form['fid'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',    
  '#value' => 1,
);
return $form['fid'];
```

And also something like:

```
   $response = parent::uploadAjaxCallback($form, $form_state, $request);
   return $response;
```

Is there a way that I can achieve return both a form element and an ajax response?

EDIT: Latest attempt is returning the form element for display but when I examine the $form from the form build function the value is still empty.

```
class MyManagedFile extends ManagedFile {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function uploadAjaxCallback(&$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state, Request $request) {


    $response = parent::uploadAjaxCallback($form, $form_state, $request);

    $form['fid'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#prefix' => '<div id="fid">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#value' => '1',
    );

    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#fid', $form['fid']));
    return $response;

  }

}
```

Examining the $form from the form builder (dpm($form)) results in:

[fid] => Array
(
[#type] => textfield
[#prefix] =>

```
        [#suffix] => 

    )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do more than simply return new markup, then your response should be an instance of `Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse`, to which you can append one or more AJAX commands via the `addCommand()` method.

A simplified version of this would be:

```
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
$response = new AjaxResponse();
$response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#my-wrapper-id', $form['fid']));
return $response;
```

I recommend checking out a tutorial, such as one of those below, for more information on using AJAX with FAPI:

- https://www.sitepoint.com/using-ajax-forms-drupal-8/
- https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/ajax-api/core-ajax-callback-commands

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've edited my question with my latest attempt. It is return the form element and populates it for viewing but the #value is not actually set when I examine the $form (dpm($form)) the #value is empty. Any idea how to resolve this?